# Is there a codec in Cassandra driver to support java 2 dimensional string arrays?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm using Datastax Cassandra Java driver. There is a pre-defined codec to map String[] to `list<text>`.

```
ObjectArrayCodec<String> stringArrayCodec = new ObjectArrayCodec<>(
      DataType.list(DataType.varchar()),
      String[].class,
      TypeCodec.varchar());
```

Is there a way to map String[][] to `list<list<text>` ?

Comment: How big is this String[][] ? does it change a lot? what is it used for? While you can probably do a multi level collection its really inefficient and has some pretty heavy performance costs and theres some good alternatives with data model changes if willing to put a little more code into it.

Comment: String[][] is not very big, approximately String[10][30]. Doesn't change a lot.   
Which is an alternative data model ?